# Magento Home Page Layout

Tags: magento

Why does my page.xml file not change the layout of the homepage?? It changes the layouts of the other pages, but not the homepage. Does the homepage have its own layout xml file??

Comment: Have you cleared you cache? You might have but saying because this thing trip alot of newcomers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figured it out. You have to go to the admin panel -> CMS -> and change the layout for the homepage to match your layout.

For example:

Mine was not working b/c page.xml was using a single column layout whereas the homepage was using a two column layout. - it goofed it all up.

Just match the layouts.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just learning Magento. Lots of little parts and pieces that can mess you up.